# Wave Einstein Analytics filter relative dates in dataflow with filter node

Tags: json, einstein-analytics, filters, analytics, saql

I need to filter opportunities in my dataflow that have a date 'last month' to 'end of current year'. I cannot use filters in the sfdcDigest node as I am doing a couple of calculations later that need values - otherwise the dataflow gives an error because fields are empty ( In the beginning I have a revenue field for each month and when I filter before performing the calculation a couple of the fields are completely empty). I checked the help page regarding the expressions and parameters for filter nodes but could not figure out how to express my requirement. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add the filter after the calculation node(s), and set the source of the filter node to the final calculation node (or whichever calculation node works in your situation).